# SFTP/SSH Java agent in Domino

Tags: java, sftp, lotus-domino

I'm currently investigating for a client a solution where he wants to send and receive files using sftp in Domino.
I have looked on the net for API's covering this and found one recommended more than others; [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).
One reason for choosing this API is for its use by others including Eclipse.

What I'd like to know is:

- if there're any obsticales using this Library? If so, can you recommend any other?
- are there any other caveats using sftp in Domino Java?
- does Domino JVM support JavaTM Cryptography Extension (JCE)?
- can we use Dominos self-signed certificates here, with Dominos CA?

/Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Sending. This should work, but you will probably have to deal with the JVM's Security Manager ("/jvm/lib/security/java.policy") of Domino to get a socket, ...

2) Receiving: You probably don't want to implement a SSH server inside domino. It's much easier and more secure to use the SSH server of the host and periodicaly scoop up the inbound files via an Agent.
Dominos Self Signed SSL certificates have nothing to do with SSH as implemented by JSch.

3) The Domino JVm will probably support theJavaTM Cryptography Extension (JCE). Watch out for the supported [JRE versions of Domino](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21188789).

4) Generally: Are you sure, you want to implement it that way? Probably way easier are either [WebServices](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/tutorials/lsdomino7ws/) or a [REST](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8JGGPE)-[API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-rest/), both via [SSL/TLS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21114148) and optionally facilitating [client certificates](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-SSL_client_authentication/).

Comment: Thx for your input. I'll check with my client. It's to a bank (I assume) and they are rigid in security but also old school…
The server is running at least 8.5.2